# URL syntax like: www.example.com/index.html#/page What does it mean?

Tags: html

If there would be no forward slash char - it would be definitely a fragment identifier.
I found a web-site using this syntax: http://themes.iki-bir.com/jupither
And I don't get an idia how it works.
Could anyone explain?

Answer (score 1):

> If there would be no forward slash char - it would be definitely a fragment identifier.

Indicated by the first `#` character, `/page` *is* the fragment identifier of this URI.

The [fragment identifier component may contain `/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20441627/1591669).

What this fragment identifier is used for? That’s up to the webmaster.

Answer (score 0):

Can't really be sure what they are doing, but what I saw there was this:

http://themes.iki-bir.com/jupither/#

and clicking on it took me to it without any changes:

http://themes.iki-bir.com/jupither/#

It's possible to have your web server serve pages to paths or to virtual paths, that are not actual folders.  Like for example you could serve pages out of a data base directly to the web server.

Comment: your idea is clear, but I used this template on my own server as well and there was no .htaccess file so I'd suppose that web-server should process the URL as it passed from address line.